# Volkswagen Golf 2.0 01 Automatic Transmission

Tags: golf, mk4

I have a 2001 Automatic. Golf mk4. 
With 166,000 on it. 
My transmission suddenly went out. About a few months after having it serviced ,started slipping  , would feel loss of power , delay in shifting.  Maybe the solenoids went bad. Or the trans valve ? Shift linkgage ?  My point is.  How can i go about solving this prob.
I live in California.
Any mechanic 
Recommendations?Just looking for common groung im a nb. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Anything from no oil to a broken shaft... need more info.

Comment: Well my engines runs and turns over with no problem at about 4500 rpm when the car is in drive you move at less than 5mph. Transmission has just be serviced at 166,000

Comment: Add that info to your question and make it coherent with any other useful info so we can have a chance at better understanding your problem.

Comment: do you have obdii scanner device ?